# Deserialize a Kotlin Data Class with Google HTTP Client

Tags: kotlin, gson

I am using Google HTTP Client to make an API request, and I would like the to use the `parseAs()` method to deserialize the JSON response for me. My model is a Kotlin data class, but the deserializer fails to instantiate my class:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unable to create new instance of class com.ippontech.blog.stats.model.GitFile because it has no accessible default constructor
```

Here is my Kotlin data class:

```
data class GitFile(
        val name: String,
        @SerializedName("download_url") val downloadUrl: String)
```

And the code I use:

```
val requestFactory = NetHttpTransport().createRequestFactory{
    it.setParser(JsonObjectParser(GsonFactory()))
}

val request = requestFactory.buildGetRequest(
        GenericUrl("https://api.github.com/repos/ippontech/blog-usa/contents/posts"))
val type = object : TypeToken<List<GitFile>>() {}.type
val rawResponse = request.execute().parseAs(type)
```

On the other hand, if I retrieve the response as a string, and then use the Gson parser, it works fine:

```
val requestFactory = NetHttpTransport().createRequestFactory()
val request = requestFactory.buildGetRequest(
        GenericUrl("https://api.github.com/repos/ippontech/blog-usa/contents/posts"))
val rawResponse = request.execute().parseAsString()
val type = object : TypeToken<List<GitFile>>() {}.type
val gitFiles: List<GitFile> = Gson().fromJson(rawResponse, type)
```

This seems to indicate that `JsonObjectParser` is not quite doing its job here.

Versions I'm using:

```
compile 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.2.30'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-sheets:v4-rev512-1.23.0'
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-gson:1.23.0'
```

Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the underlying `JsonObjectParser` methods use `newInstance` in:

```java
public static <T> T newInstance(Class<T> clazz) {
    try {
        return clazz.newInstance();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException var2) {
        throw handleExceptionForNewInstance(var2, clazz);
    } catch (InstantiationException var3) {
        throw handleExceptionForNewInstance(var3, clazz);
    }
}
```

whilst your `GitFile` has the only constructor that is not the default one (no-args), and it clearly tells you that.

From one point of view, you might add the default one like this:

```
data class GitFile(
        val name: String,
        @SerializedName("download_url") val downloadUrl: String
) {
    constructor() : this(name = "", downloadUrl = "")
}
```

This won't fail, but seems to work wrong: the parsed objects properties were all `null` for me (and I have no idea what I'm missing while configuring the `JsonObjectParser` instance).

Gson does not need default constructors and can work seamless.
But it seems to require a custom `ObjectParser` implementation that, I believe, would work even faster:

```
class GsonObjectParser(private val gson: Gson) : ObjectParser {

    override fun <T : Any?> parseAndClose(inputStream: InputStream?, charset: Charset?, clazz: Class<T>?): T {
        return doParseAndClose(InputStreamReader(inputStream, charset), clazz);
    }

    override fun parseAndClose(inputStream: InputStream?, charset: Charset?, type: Type?): Any {
        return doParseAndClose(InputStreamReader(inputStream, charset), type);
    }

    override fun <T : Any?> parseAndClose(reader: Reader?, clazz: Class<T>?): T {
        return doParseAndClose(reader, clazz);
    }

    override fun parseAndClose(reader: Reader?, type: Type?): Any {
        return doParseAndClose(reader, type);
    }

    private fun <T : Any?> doParseAndClose(reader: Reader?, type: Type?): T {
        JsonReader(reader).use {
            return gson.fromJson(reader, type);
        };
    }

}
```

```
data class GitFile(
    val name: String?,
    val downloadUrl: String?
)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    val gson = GsonBuilder()
            .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES)
            .create();
    val requestFactory = NetHttpTransport().createRequestFactory {
        it.setParser(GsonObjectParser(gson))
    }
    val request = requestFactory.buildGetRequest(GenericUrl("https://api.github.com/repos/ippontech/blog-usa/contents/posts"))
    val type = object : TypeToken<List<GitFile>>() {}.type
    val gitFiles = request.execute().parseAs(type) as List<GitFile>
    gitFiles
            .stream()
            .map { gitFile -> gitFile.name + ": " + gitFile.downloadUrl }
            .forEach { gitFile -> System.out.println(gitFile) }
}
```

Some first lines of the output as of today:

```
10-tips-and-tricks-for-cassandra.md: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ippontech/blog-usa/master/posts/10-tips-and-tricks-for-cassandra.md
5-laws-every-developer-should-know.md: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ippontech/blog-usa/master/posts/5-laws-every-developer-should-know.md
a-journey-into-blockchain-private-network-with-ethereum.md: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ippontech/blog-usa/master/posts/a-journey-into-blockchain-private-network-with-ethereum.md
```